# In MATLAB, how can you have a callback execute while a slider is being dragged?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, callback, slider, matlab-guide

I have created a MATLAB GUI using GUIDE. I have a slider with a callback function. I have noticed that this callback, which is supposed to execute 'on slider movement', in fact only runs once the slider has been moved and the mouse released.

Is there a way to get a script to run as the slider is being dragged, for live updating of a plot? There would I presume need to be something to stop the script being run too many times.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though the callback of the slider isn't being called as the mouse is moved, the [`'Value'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.control.uicontrol-properties.html#bt6ck7c-1-Value) of the slider uicontrol **is** being updated. Therefore, you could create a listener using [`addlistener`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html) that will execute a given callback when the `'Value'` property changes. Here's an example:

```
hSlider = uicontrol('Style', 'slider', 'Callback', @(s, e) disp('hello'));
hListener = addlistener(hSlider, 'Value', 'PostSet', @(s, e) disp('hi'));
```

As you move the slider you should see `'hi'` being printed to the screen (the listener callback), and when you release the mouse you will see `'hello'` printed (the uicontrol callback).

Comment: Thanks, this example basically does what I want to do. I have one question though; what does the `@(s, e)` do before the `disp` function? I guess the `@` creates the handle to disp, but what is the `(s, e)`?

Comment: @Bill: The `@(s,e)` creates an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) that takes as input arguments `s` and `e` and executes `disp(...)`. Using [function handles as callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f16-999606.html#f16-1001315) requires that the function accepts at least two arguments, even if they aren't used. These arguments are the handle of the object issuing the callback (`s`) and the event data it optionally provides (`e`). More descriptive names would be `hObject` and `eventData`, but I was keeping things short.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record, this subject is discussed in detail here: http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/continuous-slider-callback/ - several alternative solutions are presented there. gnovice's solution using `addlistener` is equivalent to the `handle.listener alternative`, since `addlistener` is basically just a wrapper for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the same original callback you passed to `uicontrol` you can add this generic listener which bootstraps the existing callback:

```
sld.addlistener('Value','PostSet',@(src,data) data.AffectedObject.Callback(data.AffectedObject,struct('Source',data.AffectedObject,'EventName','Action')));
```

[Related blog post](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=4098)