# image is too big to fit in the screen (MATLAB)

Tags: image, matlab, plot, zooming

I know that it is just a warning and it will not affect the code .. but my problem is that I need to show the image in its real size without any zooming out .. is that possible in `imshow` function are there any parameters that do this?

thank you all

Comment: have you considered using [IMTOOL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imtool.html)?

Comment: I tried it .. it works .. but I want `imshow` to do that because of saving issues using `print`.. `imtool` will not enable me to save the figure

Comment: similar question: [MATLAB: showing an image in its original size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427602/matlab-showing-an-image-in-its-original-size)

Answer (score 3):

One solution that should work is to display the image and then change the axes limits so that there is one screen pixel for every image pixel:

```
%# read an image and make it large
img = imread('autumn.tif');
img = repmat(img,[10,10]);

%# turn off the warning temporarily, we're going to fix the problem below
%# Note that in R2011b, the warning ID is different!
warningState = warning('off','Images:initSize:adjustingMag');
figure
imshow(img)
warning(warningState);


%# get axes limits in pixels
set(gca,'units','pixels')
pos = get(gca,'position')

%# display the top left part of the image at magnification 100%
xlim([0.5 pos(3)-0.5]),ylim([0.5 pos(4)-0.5])
```

Now you can select the hand (pan tool) and move the image around as needed.

Comment: very cool :-). You could add `s=warning('off','Images:initSize:adjustingMag');
figure,imshow(img);
warning(s);` to avoid the warning message...

Comment: (deleting old comments which no longer apply...)

Comment: @Jonas Heidelberg: Good point! Unfortunately, I have only installed the pre-release, where there's yet another different set of warning IDs, so I can't make my answer R2011b compatible yet.

Comment: @Jonas: Check the PDF file attached at the end of this page: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-ERAFNC/?solution=1-ERAFNC

Comment: @Amro: Nice! I did in fact request such a document after the prerelease came out; I'm glad they made it.

Answer (score 3):

The solution given by [@Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406421/image-is-too-big-to-fit-in-the-screen-matlab/7408880#7408880), which I already upvoted, is really good. Let me suggest some minor improvements so that it handles the case when the figure is resized:

```
%# read an image and make it large
img = imread('autumn.tif');
img = repmat(img, [10 10]);

%# new figure
hFig = figure;

%# try show image at full size (suppress possible warning)
s = warning('off', 'Images:initSize:adjustingMag');
imshow(img, 'InitialMagnification',100, 'Border','tight')
warning(s);

%# handle figure resize events
hAx = gca;
set(hFig, 'ResizeFcn',{@onResize,hAx})

%# call it at least once
feval(@onResize,hFig,[],hAx);

%# enable panning tool
pan on
```

the following is the resize callback function:

```
function onResize(o,e,hAx)
    %# get axes limits in pixels
    oldUnits = get(hAx, 'Units');    %# backup normalized units
    set(hAx, 'Units','pixels')
    pos = get(hAx, 'Position');
    set(hAx, 'Units',oldUnits)       %# restore units (so it auto-resize)

    %# display the top left part of the image at magnification 100%
    xlim(hAx, [0 pos(3)]+0.5)
    ylim(hAx, [0 pos(4)]+0.5)
end
```

[image: screenshot]

You could probably improve this further so that when you resize the figure, you don't always go back to the top-left corner, but maintain the current position.

Comment: thank you .. :) .. but it doesn't work .. I think it didn't work because of the huge size of the image .. it is `1914-by- 2294`

Comment: @OmarOsama: what exactly has gone wrong? It is working just fine for me. BTW the tiled image size in the example above is 2060x3450..

Answer (score 0):

Note: To centre the image (instead of showing its top left), use

```
    xlim([(w_image - w_window) / 2, (w_image + w_window) / 2]);
    ylim([(h_image - h_window) / 2, (h_image + h_window) / 2]);
```

where w_image and h_image are the image's dimensions, and w_window and h_window are the above answers' pos(3) and pos(4), respectively.