# showing .tif images in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to show a .tif image in matlab and I use these two line of codes

a = imread('C:\Users\sepideh\Desktop\21_15.tif');
 imshow(a)

that encounters this warning

Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 3%

> In imuitools\private\initSize at 73
>     In imshow at 262

what is the cause of this warning and what can I do to fix that?
the main trouble is it sometimes doesn't show the image and of course even if it shows the image CPU usage gets high that I can't zoom properly

Answer (score 0):

Use normalized units and multiply by the image size.

You can try this:

```
plot_size = get(0,'ScreenSize');
fg = figure(1);
set(fg, 'Color', [1 1 1], 'Position', plot_size, 'Visible', 'on');
a = imread('C:\Users\sepideh\Desktop\21_15.tif');
imshow(a)
```

Or check the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406421/image-is-too-big-to-fit-in-the-screen-matlab/7408880#7408880) by @Jonas

Comment: set(gcf, 'Units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);

Comment: I tried your code.It encounters the same warning and the suggested solution encounters this error with my own image??? Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> repmat at 92
            B = A(mind,nind);

Answer (score -1):

try "image(a)"

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html

I succeeded with this.