# Show image in matlab axis in its original scale

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to show image in a axes in its original scale. Currently when I load image to axes, image is modified to fit with axes. Can anyone please tell me how can I show an image in an axes in its original scale.

Comment: Maybe this - `imagesc(image_data),axis image`

Comment: @Divakar - afaik `imagesc` scales colors, not size.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is:
`imshow(imgname,'InitialMagnification','fit');`

I tested this with subplot, and it only affects the current axes:
[image: imshow with supblots]

Comment: Maybe you can add `axis on` as OP was talking about `axes`. +1 for a good answer other than that.

Comment: @Divakar - I didn't understand what you meant by the 1st part of your comment. The only reason I used subplot was to create "some more" UI elements to see if the image obstructs them (after using `imshow`). When you call `subplot` it creates axes...

Comment: I am not sure how you are using `subplot`, but I have tried something like this - `subplot,imshow(image_data,'InitialMagnification','fit');` and the `axes` didn't show up, maybe a version issue, IDK. The `axes` definitely shows up with just a call to `subplot`, but with `imshow` it hides I think.

Comment: Oh... I see where the confusion stems from. I did `subplot(2,1,1)`, `subplot(2,1,2)`, `imshow`. The axes is still there... It's just hidden by default... If you want it shown you can set it using the image processing toolbox' function `IPTSETPREF(...,'ImshowAxesVisible','on')`. Look inside `imshow`, it's full of goodies :)

Answer (score 0):

The [truesize()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/truesize.html) function may be what you are looking for - it adjusts the display size of an image to `[rowsize colsize]`. You need to have the Image Processing Toolbox to be able to use this.

There is a very related question on SO, but I believe there are easier tools available now. However, the answers to it are still worth checking out, especially if the images you plan on displaying at true-size would not be fitting in the screen and you need to think about scroll-bars on the figure etc.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1427765/297353

Comment: Problem is my gui has some other buttons in addition to axes. So truesize() won't work. Any other solution?